# Find string in text file, replace 5 sets of strings separated by tab with third string

Tags: awk, sed

Hi im trying to convert a text file from this:

```
>ENSG0123456 ENST0234567 ENSP0345678 scaffold999:1234-2345 1
ENOASDOIJSADJASPDOKPOKASD
ASDOJOIASJDOIJAKDJLKASDJL
ASLDKJLKASJDLKASJDLKJASLK

>ENSG0234567 ENST0345678 ENSP0456789 scaffold9999:2345-3456 -1
POIWQELKJLKJASMDNKLSJDLKA
ASPDOILKNSDMNASDLKJSADOIM
POAKSDAMNSADOIHOADPOKSDLK
```

To this:

```
>ENSP0345678
ENOASDOIJSADJASPDOKPOKASD
ASDOJOIASJDOIJAKDJLKASDJL
ASLDKJLKASJDLKASJDLKJASLK

>ENSP0456789
POIWQELKJLKJASMDNKLSJDLKA
ASPDOILKNSDMNASDLKJSADOIM
POAKSDAMNSADOIHOADPOKSDLK
```

My level of awk/sed is not at the level at which I could come up with a solution for this problem in a reasonable timeframe. Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these will do what you want:

```
awk -F"\t" '/>/{printf ">%s\n",$3; next}1;' file.fa
```

or

```
perl -F"\t" -lane '/>/ ? print ">$F[2]" : print' file.fa
```

or, assuming you only want the peptide names (`ENSP.*`):

```
perl -pe 's/>.*(ENSP.+?)\s.*$/>\1/' file.fa
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 awk -F'\t' 'NF > 1{$0=">"$3}1' file
```

**output**

```
>ENSP0345678
ENOASDOIJSADJASPDOKPOKASD
ASDOJOIASJDOIJAKDJLKASDJL
ASLDKJLKASJDLKASJDLKJASLK

>ENSP0456789
POIWQELKJLKJASMDNKLSJDLKA
ASPDOILKNSDMNASDLKJSADOIM
POAKSDAMNSADOIHOADPOKSDLK
```

Comment: "fixed" the leading `>` char issue for the first line in each block.

Comment: what is last 1' before file? @shellter

Comment: you could write a minimally correct progrm with just `awk '1' file` and it would print all records in file. So its just a short-hand to say "print the current record".  Any non-zero value that is evaluated as part of a condition means `true`, and `true` means print this record. The script could be written as long-hand `awk '-F\t' 'NF > 1{$0=">"$3}; {print $0}' file`.

Comment: tnx upvoting @shellter

Comment: Ah, so I should read the title too then? Dang! Sorry, temporary blindness there. Fair enough and +1. Still strange though, this is a very specific format and I've never seen tabs in the id line.

Comment: Its a file from Ensembl Pre.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the assistance!